# Child vs Parent Z-index issue

Tags: html, css, z-index

I looked at several related questions but I cannt find a solution. I even tried to use the solution in this article but it didn't work for me. > https://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/

I need the "HOVER" to be ON the "bottom" div. Please note that I cann't change the declared position of the elements.

Is there a solution?

My code:

```css
.top {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
}

.hover {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
}

.bottom {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="top">top
  <div class="hover">HOVER</div>
</div>
<div class="bottom">bottom<div>
```

Comment: In short, you can't: `.top` has a **new stacking context** created once you assign `position: fixed`, so any of its children will not be on top of its siblings, no matter how high of a z-index you are using. Read more about stacking context: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context

Comment: I'm not sure what your end goal is... is this what you want to do? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gRdYYy

Comment: Hi @MichaelCoker.. I need "bottom" be over "top" ..but "HOVER" over "bottom" ... since "HOVER" is a submenu must be over all elements..

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The child element is only capable of changing within the parents region. If you try to change the childs css and it apposes the parent, the parents css will override it.

You could try to use JS to move the child outside the parent div. I would recommend using the .append() in jquery.